# How can I prevent connections being accepted once a TCP connection is accepted?

Tags: .net, .net-4.6

I have a simple server that supports a single client at any time. I use code like this to wait for that connection:

```
Socket AcceptClient(int port){
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Bind(endpoint);
    listener.Listen(1);
    socket = listener.Accept();
    return socket;
    }
```

I happened to run up a 2nd client just to see what would happen and its connection request was successful, even though my server code was not expecting it - I hadn't realised `listener` was still listening after `AcceptClient` had terminated! My server silently accepted the 2nd connection without me knowing or asking it to.

How should/can I amend `AcceptClient` to stop accepting new connections after one is accepted, while leaving `socket` valid for communication? Simply call `listener.Close()` at the end of the method?

(in practice if the connection to the client is lost, the server would return to `AcceptClient` waiting for a new connection).

Comment: Is there any issue with just not calling `Accept` again? Also, I'm pretty sure you can shutdown the listener socket after you accept the connection - the socket you get from `listener.Accept` doesn't care about what happens to `listener`. Why do you want to do this anyway? If you want to limit the number of concurrent connections, you want to do it on the application level anyway - just reject any connections that don't match your requirements. Do you want the listener's port to be reused by some other application?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. I run the app and the code above calls, and waits for a client to try and connect. If I then run up another client to try and make a connection to the same server, it is accepted _but no code on the server is run_. The client connection request is accepted rather than rejected.

Comment: From testing, adding `listener.close()` at the end of the method seems to work but I'm not sure it's correct - now you get rejection if you try to connect when not expected

Comment: Well, yeah. The socket has a pool of incoming connections - that's what the argument to `Listen` si for. This is all handled by WSA, so you have little control over it - if you need more control, you need to use UDP. What response are you expecting at the client? If you want to keep using TCP, your only real options are to either shutdown the listener socket or keep `Accept`ing the new connections and shutting down those sockets immediately (which is kind of bad). Note that `Close` and `Shutdown` are different - you should `Shutdown` first, and `Close` after that in a finally (or use `using`).

Comment: I want to do whatever the opposite of `Listen()` is so that after a connection is accepted, others are not. In my example `listener` goes out of scope after the method ends so it is bad it is still accepting connections in the background. An answer showing how to fix my method would help.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the lifetime of the socket object. You're creating a new socket as a local in the method, but never cleaning it up. That means that it will stay there until the garbage collector gets around to finalizing it, which may never happen.

`Socket` is a disposable, so you're supposed to dispose it when you're done with it. This is especially important for objects that have side-effects connected to their lifetime - a non-disposed listener socket will still receive new connections, and still occupy the listener port.

```
Socket AcceptClient(int port)
{
  using (var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                                   SocketType.Stream, 
                                   ProtocolType.Tcp))
  {
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Bind(endpoint);
    listener.Listen(1);
    socket = listener.Accept();

    // Explicit shutdown is a good idea for TCP sockets, though I'm not sure if it's needed for
    // a listener socket.
    listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

    return socket;
  }
}
```

Of course, an even better approach is to stop using the very low level `Socket` class, and instead use the slightly higher level `TcpListener`. This gives you `TcpClient` for accepted connection, and manages the lifetime of the underlying `Socket` through friendlier methods like `Start` and `Stop`. `TcpClient` itself exposes an interface more in line with how TCP works, rather than the generic send/receive pattern of plain sockets. Unless you have very special needs, I would strongly recommend using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`.

Comment: The issue I have in my current work is my application can run as client or server depending which mode some 3rd-party module is running in. I'm sure one can still abstract it but with raw `Socket` the code is identical bar a couple of lines to generate either a server or client socket. Though I suppose the `TcpXxx` route you have the same with a stream object

Comment: @Mr.Boy Server and client sockets are identical, both with `Socket` and `TcpClient`. Though you might want to consider if server and client code _should_ be identical at a level that bothers with things like sockets at all. Usually, the application code should be working with a higher level of abstraction - using domain models, or at least streams/byte array buffers. Especially when dealing with TCP, which is quite a complicated protocol to work with.

Comment: I'm talking about a Socket used as a 2-way communication pipe. In this context the server is just whichever one accepts the connection, and client is whoever requests it.